# Ruby dynamically adding keys and values to hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, key

Hello I need a bit of help.

Here is what I want to do.

1. Check if hash already has key based on a variable
2. If key already exists add new value to key
3. If key does not exists create new key and add new value to it

Here is what I got and it has many issues:

```
if @agencyList.has_key?(domain)
    @agencyList[domain] << match
else
    @agencyList[domain] = match
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, consider using the `multimap` gem. Then (assuming you use a `Multimap` instance for `@agencyList`) you'd use `@agencyList[domain] = match` to add an entry, in all cases.

Comment: There's a pretty strong convention in Ruby of only using snake_case for variable names. CamelCase is detected by the parser and is reserved for constants (class names and module names). Using camelCase with a lowercase beginning will confuse basically everybody.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your hash has **values of Array type**, and add new value to the array **rather than replacing it**. The follows can work:

```
@agency_list[domain] ||= []
@agency_list[domain] << match
```

Enjoy!

Comment: ...which you'll often see written `(@agency_list[domain] ||= []) << match`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah.., it goes further.

Answer (score 1):

Are the values of the keys arrays that you want to add the new value to, or just objects that you want to overwrite?

If they're arrays you want to add to, this should work;

```
if @agency_list.has_key?(domain)
  @agency_list[domain] << match
else
  # This way you can create the array and put the value in at the same time
  @agency_list[domain] = [match]
end
```

If they're just objects you want to overwrite, you don't even have to check if they key is there;

```
@agency_list[domain] = match
```

Comment: I don't want to overwrite. The problem is the value I add are all bunched into one element. I need them to be in separate elements.